# import from a module and put object in another object in one step

Tags: javascript, import, module

In a JavaScript file there is the following code:

```
let config = { conversions: {} };
// code that populates conversions not shown here

import { multipliers } from '../config/extension';
config.multipliers = multipliers;
```

While this code works, I'm wondering if there's a way to do the import and set `config.multiplier` in a single step.  I tried this but get a red squiggly line under the word `import` in the editor with a message that says "Expression expected" -

```
config.multipliers = import { multipliers } from '../config/extension';
```

I also tried

```
import { multipliers as config.multipliers } from '../config/universal-extension';
```

to no avail.

Comment: maybe `config.multipliers = (await import('../config/extension')).multipliers;`? not really the same 

Comment: Thanks for the suggestion.  Trying that gave an error "cannot use keyword 'await' outside an async function".